# Configure JetBrains WebStorm for Telerik's Kendo UI

Tags: kendo-ui, webstorm

I am about to start a new web development project and have chosen to use JetBrains WebStorm as my IDE (as I am familiar with IntelliJ IDEA) and Telerik's Kendo UI for the GANTT controls which I require.

Can anyone advise me how I configure WebStorm to integrate Kendo UI so that I get code completion and general ease of use?

Answer (score 2):

WebStorm provides no support for this framework.

To get completion, etc. working, you can download kendo.*.js files and set them up as JavaScript library (see https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/07/how-webstorm-works-completion-for-javascript-libraries/). Note that you need non-minified versions, types resolving works much worse when using compressed scripts. Or, even better, try using kendo-ui Typescript stubs - they can be downloaded in Settings | Languages & frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries, Download...

Note also that WebStorm knows nothing about kendo-specific HTML attributes. You can add all your k-* attributes to custom HTML tag attributes list in Settings | Editor | Inspections | HTML, Unknown HTML tag attribute: attributes from this list will be shown up in completion list and not reported as not allowed

Comment: copying my answer at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207679505-Telerik-s-Kendo-UI-Integration here just for reference

Comment: Thanks Lena. You're all over it!